# Marking Only Some List Items with a Class

Tags: jquery

I have the following list item

```
<ul id="lxx" class="lst">
  <li>arnold</li>
  <li>Becky</li>
  <li>Arnold</li>
  <li>KathY</li>
  <li>Carol</li>
  <li>ARNold</li>    
  <li>carol</li>          
</ul>
```

I am using this code which adds a class 'someClass' to all items which are repeated more than once.

```
$('#lxx li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).siblings().text().toUpperCase()
        .indexOf($(this).text().toUpperCase()) != -1;
  }).addClass('someClass');
```

However what happens is that the original item also gets highlighted using the above code, whereas I want only repeated items to get highlighted. So out of arnold, Arnold and ARNold only the last two should get highlighted. Similarly for other dups too.

How can I change my code to accommodate this? **Also is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: How would you handle 2 empty elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var texts = {};
$('#lxx li').filter(function () {
    var text = $.trim($(this).text().toLowerCase());
    if (texts[text]) {
        return true;
    }
    texts[text] = this;
    return false;
}).addClass('someClass');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hnf6a/)

Comment: ...than a speeding bullet!

Comment: @TomHodder we create a map of all the texts that we have found... it a text is repeated then that text will be already present in the objet `texts` as a key - if so then we can select the element, if the key is not found then we add the key to the object and returns false

Comment: @TomHodder looks at the console to see how the value of texts is updated http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hnf6a/4/

Comment: What does this stand here for? texts[text] = this;

Comment: @TomHodder we are adding the current element's text as the key and the element as the value to the texts object

Comment: He is using a variable named texts to store whether this particular text has been found. You are probably confused on the "this". The code could be changed to just say texts[text] = true and it would work the same way.

Comment: As a beginner, I am trying to understand whose method is better from a performance point. Yours or megawac? I really need to understand why

Comment: @TomHodder I don't think the other answer is that accurate... see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hnf6a/7/

Answer (score 3):

Your code snippet is almost correct. Just need to use [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/), which only selects previous elements, instead of `siblings`.

```
$('#lxx li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).prevAll().text().toUpperCase()
                  .indexOf($(this).text().toUpperCase()) != -1;
}).addClass('someClass');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hnf6a/3/)

Comment: Is it only me? The items are not highlighted red in your example

Comment: Works for me in chrome and ff... What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 30, ff and IE 10

Comment: Odd, jQuery was throwing an error after it loaded in IE10 http://jsfiddle.net/hnf6a/6/

Comment: My bad. Your example works fine. One last question. How can i remove all items which have a class 'someClass' on them?

Comment: `$('#lxx li:not(.someClass)')`

Comment: li:not? I need to remove them from list

Comment: Not understanding your question, what do you want to do exactly with elements with a class `someClass`?

Comment: remove them from the list. When I do $('#lxx li:not(.someClass)').remove(), it removes items which do not have .someClass. I want to do the opposite

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted to exclude them from the filter as they already had someClass. Anyway you would just do `$('#lxx li.someClass').remove();` in that case

Answer (score 1):

To make yours work, I think that slice is an option.

```
$('#lxx li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).siblings().text().toUpperCase().indexOf($(this).text().toUpperCase()) != -1;
  }).slice(1).addClass('someClass');
```

Comment: not exactly http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hnf6a/2/ - first `Carol` also is highlighted

Comment: The slice would remove only the first element. I did not investigate his code. Good point.